# why shiny reactive value didn't start to calculate in shinydashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I'm writing a shinydashboard with several pages. In first page user upload some data, and there are several `reactive()` expressions based on the user input. One of the expression take more than 1 minutes to calculate but its output is in the last page.

I was hoping that once user uploaded the data, all the reactive expressions should be calculated. Thus when user is working in first several pages, the last time consuming one could calculate in background, and it will take less user wait time when user finally move to the last page.

However from my observation this is not the case. The last expression seemed only start to calculate when the last page is activated.

If in theory my expectation is possible, I'll make a small reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, reactive elements are calculated only when they are displayed on the the page, you can force calculation with :

```
output$myplot <- renderPlot({
  plot(1)
})

outputOptions(output, "myplot", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
```

But it will probably slow down your app, since R can calculate only one thing at a time.

Comment: You are right, once I enabled it it will compete for resource in first page. I also experimented the priority option but it didn't work.

Comment: The reason this is still not enough is because Shiny doesn't know what the dimensions of the plot should be on the last page. For it to actually calculate the plot in the last page you need to both set `suspendWhenHidden = FALSE` *AND* make the height and width explicit:

`output$myplot <- renderPlot({
  plot(1)
}, height = 450, width = 600)

outputOptions(output, "myplot", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)`

Comment: Actually my reactive expression is used for a plot and a text box. With the suspendWhenHidden option itself, it started to calculate already.